# What are the steps to get a file from the web page to upload it in parts and make a seed?

Tags: javascript

How do I implement file sharding? Also how to configure and build the seeded P2P network? I found a torrenting site project on github  but all I made were dead seeds  because my tracker selection was wrong? Next is the water word count session